# Google Apps Script Export Document to Gmail

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, export, converters, google-docs

I'd like to convert a google doc to an email, like the Google function in docs: **"File > Email collaborators > "Paste the item itself into the email"**.
I tried to convert the document in html but the css-styles are not inline:

```
function convertToHtml(fileId) {
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id="+fileId+"&exportFormat=html&format=html";
  var param = {
method      : "get",
headers     : {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
muteHttpExceptions:true,
contentType : "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
  };
  var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,param).getContentText();
  return html;
}
```

I need a function to convert it in html with inline css.

eg.: 
Not inline:

```
<html>
<head>
<style> p { color: red; } </style> <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<p>Test</p>
</body>
</html>
```

inline:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<p style="color: red">Test</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Or another way to convert a Google doc to an email.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I suppose you could try HtmlService.  But it doesn't have to html.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML format that you get using **File > Email >** or **File > Download >** is the same as using **UrlFetchApp.fetch** with the endpoint you have taken. However, there is an option to get inline styles in your HTML using the [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk) with the [export](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export) method. You only have to change your `url` by

```
var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + fileId + "/export?mimeType=text%2Fhtml";
```